# Another ASP.net AJAX SYS Undefined Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax

Im at my wits end here. I have an ASP.net 2.0 Web Project Developed in VS 2008. The problem occurs on my dev XP system and our Windows 2000 and 2008 servers.
The project uses AJAX  1 and references System.Web.Extensions 1.0.61025.0 and AJAXControlTookKit 1.0.10618.0.

I am trying to use the ScriptManager and maybe the ToolKitScriptManager control to help with embedding javascript files.

Before I get to trying to embed, I have to get rid of the dreaded SYS undefined javascript error.
Actually, if I use the ScriptManager to include javascript files using the Path attribute it works. The SYS error is still there, but javascript files are included on the generated page and they work. Right now I am working with a blank page that only includes some test text. This page is wrapped in a MasterPage that includes an empty ScriptManager.

When I debug this page I get an error on Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager (see generated HTML below).

I have uninstalled and reinstalled AJAX, copied the System.Web.Extensions to my bin, checked my web.config settings at least 50 times&and have been to so many search results pages, forums, and blogs that my head is spinning.

I know its probably something simple I am overlooking. My abbreviated code is below, can someone help me think through this and catch what I am missing.

Thanks

Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    …
  </appSettings>

  <location path="PartnerPrograms">
    …
  </location>

  <system.web>
  <xhtmlConformance mode="Transitional" />
  <authentication mode="Forms">
     …
  </authentication>
  <trace enabled="false"/>
  <compilation debug="false">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </httpModules>

    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>

    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <siteMap defaultProvider="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider">
      …
    </siteMap>

  </system.web>

  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!-- Uncomment this line to customize maxJsonLength and add a custom converter -->
        <!--
      <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="500">
        <converters>
          <add name="ConvertMe" type="Acme.SubAcme.ConvertMeTypeConverter"/>
        </converters>
      </jsonSerialization>
      -->
        <!-- Uncomment this line to enable the authentication service. Include requireSSL="true" if appropriate. -->
        <!--
        <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
      -->

        <!-- Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service. To allow profile properties to be retrieved
           and modified in ASP.NET AJAX applications, you need to add each property name to the readAccessProperties and
           writeAccessProperties attributes. -->
        <!--
      <profileService enabled="true"
                      readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                      writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
      -->
      </webServices>
      <!--
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
      -->
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***MasterPage***

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Codebehind="…" Inherits="…" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    …
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager" />
…
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Content ASPX Page***

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="…" Inherits="…" MasterPageFile="…" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
    Hello from TestMaster.aspx
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

***Generated HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title>
    <link href="App_Themes/GFYStyle/main-styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="App_Themes/GFYStyle/menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="testmaster.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTEwMDUyNjYzMjhkZA==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=_WiqftJEACb-AG_CJoE3Ow2&amp;t=633918597608321164" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=ijkJL7RSAe839q84O1r7AVMBB0ct2fvAOK5xpjCeZxrwP0ygLeMB_n15PEMyX4_bqkpJiL-kZfiCFgkZo8QpQuTDwrSUkIcLrOxl8UfjJBc1&amp;t=633921693043429658" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=ijkJL7RSAe839q84O1r7AVMBB0ct2fvAOK5xpjCeZxrwP0ygLeMB_n15PEMyX4_bqkpJiL-kZfiCFgkZo8QpQjLl6r3RCBV1yA4P_b8fb641&amp;t=633921693043429658" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls([], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>

    <div>

    <div>
    Hello from TestMaster.aspx
    </div>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i have faced this problem before,

search for the embedded javascript files in ajaxtoolkit and see the modified date for it.
and be ensure to be not in the future.

to be sure about that, check links appear in viewsource with *.axd and try to run eveyone, if you see someone response an error, here you found the problem.

My Regards

Comment: I may sound stupid, but still: Give I have found the *.axd, what to do with it? In my case it results in a HTTP Status code 500, but what do I do with this information?

Comment: If you found some file response 500 error, and you are sure that file is present in "ajaxtoolkit" before build, try to change last modified date by any tool, that mean that you build your dll in a wrong future date.